# Encong: Is it possible a field just informative?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, encog

Is it possible add to my train/eval csvs a field not input nor output, just informative? Just like additional information to each line

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do not map that field to an input neuron.  How you do that depends on how you are preprocessing the data.  Encog does not force you to use any data, if you do not want to use it, don't put it into the training dataset. Without more information that is about as clear as I can be.